# How can i create a Gridview to make Ajax calls to webservice 

Tags: .net, asp.net, ajax

I Have a Gridview . I wanted to display data from Webservice via Ajax calls in ASP.net  Please ,let me know the solution for this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: We're going to need a lot more than that to go on...

Comment: Are you trying to populate the GridView via AJAX requests?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too sure if I understood you correctly but there is no way to bind a Grid View with an AJAX call (yet). This is simply because you are dealing with the client side and a Grid View is just a HTML table. You will have to write your on custom method to handle your AJAX response and build a table on the fly....I've done this before and it works quite well...

If you really want to go down this path I recommend you seeing this jQuery [plugin](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) that enables table sorting and paging...it's pretty cool ...

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just create a method to call the web service and return your data object/dataset and then bind that to your grid and wrap the grid in an update panel, on the method end call myUDP.Update() to refresh the grid with the newly bound data.